# Laravel 8 - wire:model on input not working

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to work with livewire and i cant get it working.

I have a route:

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
    ->get('/nuevoturno', NuevoTurno::class)
    ->name('nuevoturno');
```

The NuevoTurno.php contains:

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\FormatoTurno;
use Livewire\Component;

class NuevoTurno extends Component
{

    public $qFecha = '2020-11-17';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.nuevo-turno',[
            'formatoTurno' => FormatoTurno::First()
        ]);
    }

}
```

The livewire view:

```
@section('header', 'Nuevo Turno')

@section('content')
{{ $qFecha }}
<input type="text" value="{{ $qFecha }}">
<div>
    <br>
    {{-- A good traveler has no fixed plans and is not intent upon arriving. --}}
    {{ $formatoTurno->Distancia_Entre_Turnos }}
    {{ $formatoTurno->Hora_Inicio }}
    {{ $formatoTurno->Hora_Fin }}
</div>
@endsection
```

{{ $qFecha }} is showing, but the input is not filled

So.. What's goin on?

EDIT:
I changed @section('content') to  and in app.blade.php changed @yield('content') to {{ $slot }}
And now it appears:

```
< wire:id="BCEos1ECXtGL114CYnTn" wire:initial-data="{"fingerprint":{"id":"BCEos1ECXtGL114CYnTn","name":"nuevo-turno","locale":"es"},"effects":{"listeners":[]},"serverMemo":{"children":[],"errors":[],"htmlHash":"850cd1b2","data":{"qFecha":"2020-11-17"},"dataMeta":[],"checksum":"3cb32d8a817d51f7ff71a9ebeb184da10fb421dc1eb00e1ddd53a4ab30dcefb7"}}"!doctype html>
```

Comment: Livewire now assumes by default that you use the slot/component based approach rather than sections and extensions. That said, from the docs https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/upgrading: "*Livewire uses the same layout file as a default, however, it now expects you are using the new Blade component $slot syntax in the layout.*".

Comment: Also, as a note, your Livewire components should only have *one* single root element. You can wrap your entire component in a `<div>`. See https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components under "*Returning Blade Views*" it'll say "*Make sure your Blade view only has ONE root element.*"

Comment: If you have an answer, then post an answer. don't edit it in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLUTION]
I changed app.blade format from `@yield()` to `{{ $slot }}`.
Also changed livewire component nuevo-turno.blade:

```
<x-slot name="header">
    Nuevo Turno
</x-slot>

<div>
    {{ $qFecha }}
    <input type="text" value="{{ $qFecha }}">
    <div>
        <br>
        {{-- A good traveler has no fixed plans and is not intent upon arriving. --}}
        {{ $formatoTurno->Distancia_Entre_Turnos }}
        {{ $formatoTurno->Hora_Inicio }}
        {{ $formatoTurno->Hora_Fin }}
    </div>
</div>
```

And now it works.
Thanks everybody for the answers!